# Dependency Injection Strict Mode (ng-strict-di) raises error even when array notation is used

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I am trying to implement ng-strict-di in Angular to check my code for minification. Even though I am using array notation, it tells me that I am not explicitly defining my dependencies.

> function(sitesService is not using explicit annotation and cannot be
>   invoked in strict mode

Here is my code:

```
angular.module('app').factory('sitesService', ['$q', '$http', 'globalContextService', '$rootScope', '$log', function ($q, $http, globalContextService, $rootScope, $log) {
    return {
        ...
    };
}]);
```

To make sure it wasn't an included dependency, I tried this which also doesn't work:

```
angular.module('app').factory('sitesService', [function () {
    return {

    };
}]);
```

The error page returned from Angular is below which also shows the same notation I am already using in their second example:
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi?p0=function(sitesService

Comment: May be your javascript is cached..

Comment: Nothing is cached. I always ctrl-f5 with debugger tools open and disable cache checked. Also I tested in firefox as well to make sure.

Comment: Make sure wherever you are using `sitesService` is also properly annotated. The error message is not pointing to the service, instead where it is used.

Comment: yeh just noticed that when searching around for the text sitesService. I was missing the notation on my resolves: resolve: {
           data: ['sitesService', function (sitesService) {
               return sitesService.getSites();
           }]
       }

Comment: Sure added an answer, thx!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the error message

> function(sitesService is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode

may be a bit misleading, it says that wherever you have injected `siteService` it has not been explicitly annotated. So you would need to look for places where `siteService` is being injected and not explicitly annotated. If the issue had been with `siteService` then you would see similar message regarding the dependencies of `siteService`. Example:

> function($q, $http, globalContextService, $rootScope, $log is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode

Comment: Thanks for extra details as well!