# What is causing a dependency injection failure in an AngularJS directive?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm getting a dependency injection error with the code below. I'm not sure why, because `rosterStateHelper` works in other files, including the one I am copying some code from.

```
angular.module("HmComponents")
.directive(
    "dhtmlxScheduler", [
        "$rootScope",
        "ModalService",
        "rosterStateHelper",    // <- This line is causing an error
        function (
            $rootScope,
            modal_service,
            rosterStateHelper   // <- This line is causing an error
        ) {
```

I've found this question which appears to be the same issue as mine: [Dependency Injection Strict Mode (ng-strict-di) raises error even when array notation is used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31732156/1166898) but I don't understand the accepted (and only) answer. Is it saying that there is an error on a different usage of `rosterStateHelper`? If that is the case, why does removing the two lines I've marked stop the error from appearing in the console?

There's something different about my new usage from the others, but I can't work out what it is and how to fix it. The only difference I can see is that the other usages are all in controllers, whereas mine is in a directive.

The error is:

> rosterStateHelper ... is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode

which is the more specific version of https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi

[At Phil's request, here is the full link using the non-minified library.](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi?p0=rosterStateHelper%20minErr%2F<@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:63:12%20annotate@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:3413:17%20invoke@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:4116:21%20enforcedReturnValue@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:3991:20%20invoke@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:4138:14%20createInjector%2FinstanceCache.$injector<@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:3956:20%20getService@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:4097:39%20invoke@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:4129:13%20registerDirective%2F<%2F<@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:6431:33%20forEach@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:322:11%20registerDirective%2F<@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:6429:13%20invoke@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:4138:14%20enforcedReturnValue@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:3991:20%20invoke@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:4138:14%20createInjector%2FinstanceCache.$injector<@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:3956:20%20getService@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:4097:39%20directiveIsMultiElement@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:7740:42%20collectDirectives@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:7076:17%20compileNodes@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:6927:22%20compileNodes@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:6943:15%20compileNodes@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:6943:15%20compile@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:6838:15%20bootstrapApply%2F<@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:1439:11%20$RootScopeProvider%2Fthis.$get<%2FScope.prototype.$eval@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:14287:16%20$RootScopeProvider%2Fthis.$get<%2FScope.prototype.$apply@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:14385:18%20bootstrapApply@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:1437:9%20invoke@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:4138:14%20bootstrap%2FdoBootstrap@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:1435:5%20bootstrap@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:1455:12%20angularInit@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:1349:5%20@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Fu91622b:25910:5%20jQuery.Callbacks%2Ffire@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Fjquery-1.11.3.js%3Fuf04dc5:3148:26%20jQuery.Callbacks%2Fself.fireWith@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Fjquery-1.11.3.js%3Fuf04dc5:3260:29%20.ready@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Fjquery-1.11.3.js%3Fuf04dc5:3472:13%20completed@http:%2F%2Fdev.homecare%2Fjs%2Fjquery-1.11.3.js%3Fuf04dc5:3503:13)

InitRosterHelper.ts (see updated version below)

```
/// <reference path="../../../../../js/lib/typeDefinitions/angular.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="RosterModel.ts" />
/// <reference path="RosterStateHelper.ts" />

import RosterModel = Roster.RosterModel;
import RosterStateHelper = Roster.RosterStateHelper;

angular.module('RosterHelpers', ['ngRoute'])
    .factory('rosterDataModel', ($http) => {
        return new RosterModel($http);
    })
    .factory('rosterStateHelper', ($location) => {
        return new RosterStateHelper($location);
    })
;
```

RosterStateHelper.ts

```
/// <reference path="../../../../../js/lib/typeDefinitions/angular.d.ts" />

module Roster {
    import ILocationService = angular.ILocationService;

    export class RosterStateHelper {
        private internalState = {};
        private $location: ILocationService;

        constructor($location) {
            this.$location = $location;
        }

        /**
         * Get the key from internal store
         * @param key
         * @returns {*}
         */
        getInternalState(key) {
            return this.internalState[key];
        }

        /**
         * Save the value for key in internal store.
         * Used to move values between separate controllers
         * @param key
         * @param value
         */
        keepInternalState(key, value) {
            this.internalState[key] = value;
        }

        /**
         * Persist key/values in the page URL.
         * @param key
         * @param value
         */
        keepState(key, value) {
            this.$location.search(key, value);
        }

        /**
         * Retrieve key/values from the page URL
         * @param key
         * @returns {*}
         */
        getState(key) {
            let state = this.$location.search();
            if (state[key] === 'false') {
                return false;
            }
            return state[key];
        }
    }
}
```

Updated InitRosterHelper.ts - still the same error:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../../js/lib/typeDefinitions/angular.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="RosterModel.ts" />
/// <reference path="RosterStateHelper.ts" />

import IHttpService = angular.IHttpService;
import ILocationService = angular.ILocationService;
import RosterModel = Roster.RosterModel;
import RosterStateHelper = Roster.RosterStateHelper;

angular.module('RosterHelpers', ['ngRoute'])
    .factory('rosterDataModel', ($http: IHttpService) => {
        return new RosterModel($http);
    })
    .factory('rosterStateHelper', ($location: ILocationService) => {
        return new RosterStateHelper($location);
    })
;
```

Comment: what error do you see?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari One of those really huge ones that you have to go to the website for.

Comment: And the link for that error is....?

Comment: @Phil i guess https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi

Comment: Sounds like the problem is that `rosterStateHelper` does not use DI annotation. Where does it come from?

Comment: @Phil It's defined in another file. The controllers have no problem using it and I get no errors when I comment out the usage in the directive.

Comment: Can you please show the full error message and / or the full error link that includes files and locations? If you use the unminified version of `angular.js`, the error messages are more verbose

Comment: @Phil Done, but I don't think you'll find it useful.

Comment: Like I said, switch to the unminified version of `angular.js` while developing

Comment: @Phil See updated non-minified link.

Comment: where is the code for `rosterStateHelper`?  as @phil has stated, that file *is declared incorrectly*, and therefore cannot be injected into an app that is using `ng-strict-di`.  If you cannot fix the `rosterStateHelper`, then your only option is to remove `ng-strict-di` from your `ng-app` in your index.html.

Comment: From the [documentation for `ng-app`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp): "ng-strict-di (optional): if this attribute is present on the app element, the injector will be created in "strict-di" mode. This means that the application will fail to invoke functions which do not use explicit function annotation (and are thus unsuitable for minification)"

Comment: @Claies See update

Comment: so even though that class is written in TypeScript, it still clearly is not using StrictDi.  It's not really clear if the TypeScript output would be using StrictDI, but this would not be compatible with `ng-strict-di` as written.  Specifically, in the line `.factory('rosterStateHelper', ($location) =>`, `$location` isn't clearly defined, and if the file were minified, you would have something like  `.factory('rosterStateHelper', (a) =>`, and no other file would know what `a` represents.

Comment: @Claies What's clear? It's not clear to me which is why I'm still here!

Comment: Please search the usages of rosterStateHelper, you are missing notation somewhere.

Comment: @ManishSingh I've already searched all the usages of `rosterStateHelper` and they weren't helpful.

Comment: I was updating my comment at the same time you were requesting more info, sorry for the overlap.

Comment: @Claies OK, thanks! So `$location` is an object of `angular.ILocationService` because of `import ILocationService = angular.ILocationService;` and `private $location: ILocationService;`. How do I make that explicit?

Comment: the problem is in the lines (there are two) that look like `.factory('rosterStateHelper', ($location) => {`.  Try `.factory('rosterStateHelper',['$location', ($location) => {  ...  }])` (and the same with the other, referencing `$http`.

Comment: @Claies Should I keep the types I just added?

Comment: no, I don't think the types are helpful here.

Comment: @Claies Brilliant! That seems to have done it! That error has disappeared and I'm now getting a similar error about something else, so I should be able to apply the same fix! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue derives from the optional `ng-strict-di` annotation. `ng-strict-di` can be added to the `ng-app` element in your HTML, to trap potential errors that might occur due to Dependency Injection errors caused from JavaScript Minification.  When `ng-strict-di` is enabled, any components that are not declared using minification safe methods will not be injected, and this error will be generated instead.

In your specific case, we are dealing with the line

```
.factory('rosterStateHelper', ($location) => {
```

The `.factory` `'routerStateHelper'` has a dependency on `$location`, which angular will need to find at runtime.  Since the injection is supplied at runtime, TypeScript types don't provide enough information to know where this will be supplied from.  Therefore, additional details must be provided, and this is what the array notation is used for:

```
.factory('rosterStateHelper',['location', ($location) => {
```

As an alternative, you could use a variation on the declaration:

```
.factory('rosterStateHelper', ($location) => {
    var helper = new RosterStateHelper($location);
    helper.$inject = [$location];
    return helper;
})
```